# PHP calculate sum of 2 columns in MySQL query WHERE id matches

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called textinv which I am using to record books added and subtracted to and from my inventory. I have textinv_textbook_id, textinv_qty_in, and textinv_qty_out columns along with a few others. (So, each record of the table either records an addition or subtraction of a specific book.)

I want to be able to display the total number of books on hand by totaling textinv_qty_in and subtracting the total for textinv_qty_out by textinv_textbook_id. (In other words, I only want to total those values in the column where the record matches the book I am looking at.) Here is my query.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT textinv_id, textinv_qty_in - textinv_qty_out 
          AS textinv_qty_total FROM textinv 
          WHERE textinv_id = textbookId";

$result = mysqli_query($dbConn, $query) 
          or die('Textinv query failed: '.mysqli_error($dbConn));
?>
```

My query is failing and as I have no formal education in programming, I can't seem to figure out how to achieve this. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: you can do "math" in queries: `select field1 - field3 + field3 as result from ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to sum the in and outs of each book, and get an inventory list:

Try this query, and if it's the right direction

```
SELECT SUM(textinv_qty_in - textinv_qty_out) AS textinv_qty_total 
FROM textinv GROUP BY textinv_id
```

And for book with id 123:

```
SELECT SUM(textinv_qty_in - textinv_qty_out) AS textinv_qty_total 
FROM textinv WHERE textinv_id=123
```

Comment: Thank you Uri. I think this is the right direction. I was missing the SUM.I have two tables. 'textbook' contains all the details of the book such as publisher etc. 'textinv' contains just the inventory in and out records. On my website I have a Textbook Search page. This is where I want it to display all of the information from the 'textbook' table for the selected book and calculate/display the total on hand from the 'textinv' table for that same book. How would I modify this query to include yours?    $query = "SELECT * FROM textbook WHERE textbook_id = '$textbookId' ";

Comment: right. by the way, If my answer was helpful please accept the answer or at least vote up